# Python - Reduce size of data base

Tags: python, database, pandas, reduce

I am new in Python. I need to work on a data base that seems too big (hence crashing the memory).
Here are the details:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4747156 entries, 0 to 4747155
Data columns (total 5 columns):
User             int64
Date_and_time    object
Latitude         float64
Longitude        float64
Location_id      object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 217.3+ MB
```

How can I reduce the size to be able to work on it? Especially, there are some irrelevant lines that I need to get rid off.

My database looks like this:

`locations_df.head()`

```
User    Date_and_time   Latitude    Longitude   Location_id
0   2010-10-17T01:48:53Z    39.747652   -104.992510 88c46bf20  
0   2010-10-16T06:02:04Z    39.891383   -105.070814 7a0f8898
```

Some lines are irrelevant because Latitude and Longitude are equal to 0.0 and I need to get rid of these (there are a lot of them) because it's useless

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: explain the nature of your irrelevant lines

Comment: My database looks like this:

`locations_df.head()`

 User Date_and_time Latitude Longitude Location_id
0 0 2010-10-17T01:48:53Z 39.747652 -104.992510 88c46bf20
1 0 2010-10-16T06:02:04Z 39.891383 -105.070814 7a0f8898

Some lines are irrelevant because Latitude and Longitude are equal to 0.0 and I need to get rid of these (there are a lot of them) because it's useless

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Mitch : Can you export this to csv or text to work with? I am sure pandas handles csv really well.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new dataframework eliminating unwanted values:

```
df[df['Latitude'].isin([0])]
```

and change the types of your fields to smaller types:

```
df[['two', 'three']].astype(float)
```

the list of available types:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html

Comment: His main problem based on what I have understood is not the processing but memory crashing.

Comment: Well actually the main problem is memory crashing. I thought it would be coming from the fact that the database is huge. However, even when I eliminate the unwanted lines, the data is still too big: memory usage: 203.8+ MB

Comment: @Mitch are you reading a .csv file? Actually 203.8+ MB doesn't seem a big memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're working with a pandas dataframe `df`, you can filter the unwanted values of columns in the dataframe with:

```
df = df[(df['Latitude'] > 0) | (df['Longitude'] > 0)]
```

Assuming that you want to remove every row when both `Latitude` AND `Longitude` are equal to 0.